# Accessing webservice via apache server without using port no depolyed on tomcat server using ssl in java

Tags: java, apache, rest, tomcat, ssl

I have deployed a Java based web application(.war) using SSL configuration on port 8443 of Tomcat server. I have used Jersey REST web services jar to define web services.
I have configured mod_jk to redirect apache server requests to tomcat.But the request are getting redirected only with the help of web browser as client.
The following is the piece of code to access webservice using ssl on tomcat server using jersey jar
in java

> Client client1 = null;
>
> ```
>           com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig config =new com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig(); // SSL
>
>           config.getProperties()
>                         .put(com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES,
>                                      new com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties(
>                                                    getHostnameVerifier(), ctx));
>           client1 = Client.create(config);
>
>                  WebResource service = client1.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(
>                               properties.getProperty("LogTransmitService")).build());
> ```
>
> String res= service.post(String.class,"abc");

I want to define a Java client(Java desktop application) that will call web service without giving port number (for ex: `https://project/ws`) to Apache server.
Apache server should then redirect it to the tomcat server.Is there any Java code with which we can make calls to web services via Apache server which should be redirected to Tomcat using Jersey REST API? If not is there any other alternative with which we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure tomcat clustering with Apache, Tomcat and mod_jk to solve you problem.

Comment: I ve configured mod_jk.The problem is with the java code.Using web browser i can redirect any url accessed on apache to tomcat using mod_jk.But I need to develop a swing based application where i need to access web service with the click of a button.So the connectivity needs to be done in java.Is there any code ex in java with which we can communicate with apache server and configure it to redirect request to tomcat?